# jQuery UI Draggable: Scroll other lists when dragging over them

Tags: css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a strange issue with jQuery ui-sortable. In my example I have multiple columns and in each column I have multiple sortable items.

I want to drag and drop in any column, sorting within one column is no problem.

**I have two problems:**

- When dragging from one column to another column I need the destination column to auto scroll to the bottom.
- Horizontal scroll does not auto scroll for the column on the very right side.

See my example 
https://jsfiddle.net/maidanhcongtu/9ws2unLa/11/

```
var configuration2 = {
        cursor : 'move',
        placeholder : 'highlight',
        dropOnEmpty : true,
        connectWith : ".connectedSortable",
        containment : "body",
    };



    $(".connectedSortable").sortable(configuration2).disableSelection();
```

Comment: When I remove max height and overflow like this https://jsfiddle.net/maidanhcongtu/9ws2unLa/10/ it's working. But I just want to have a scroll in each column. how can I archive that?.

Comment: Help me understand, when you drag a sortable item over a list you want to be able to scroll down that list with that element, correct?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my snippet code I cannot scroll down in the bottom of column when drag a sortable item. And I also can not drag item to the very right side. I wonder if there is a native way to do that or I have to do it my my side with "sort or change function callback"

Comment: You could possibly do it using the "over" sortable function too, I think the problem is that the sortable item is technically still in the original sortable list, so that is the one that it is scrolling with.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found a solution to disable scrolling when you're no longer sorting in the original parent, so that the sortable item does not scroll the parent when dragging over another sortable.

I also made the sortable list you're sorting over auto scroll to the bottom.

Sorry, I changed your code up a bit because it's easier for me to keep track of things this way.

Also, I added ID's to each sortable list.

see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/ktxeu35p/46/

```
$('li').addClass('item');
var y;
var og;
var n, nB, half;
$(".connectedSortable").sortable({
  cursor : 'move',
  placeholder : 'highlight',
  dropOnEmpty : true,
  connectWith : ".connectedSortable",
  containment : "body",
  items: '.item',
  start: function(event,ui) {
    og = $(this).closest('.connectedSortable');
  },
  over: function(event,ui) {
    n = $(this).closest('.connectedSortable');
    nB = n.outerHeight(true) + n.position().top;
    half = nB / 2;
  },
  sort: function(event,ui) {
  console.log(half);
    if ( n.attr('id') != og.attr('id') ) {
        og.sortable( "option", "scroll", false );
      if (event.pageY > half) {
        n.scrollTop(n.scrollTop() + 5);
      } else if (event.pageY < half) {
        n.scrollTop(n.scrollTop() - 5);
      }
    } else {
        og.sortable( "option", "scroll", true );
    }
  }
});
```